# html_entity_decode not working in XML dom nodeValue

Tags: php, xml, entity, decode, entities

I have the test.xml file where I want these node values to be encoded:
...

```
<section id="1">
<title id="2">&gt;</title>
<title id="2">&lt;</title>
<title id="2">&lt;</title>
</section>
```

...

So i wrote this code but after it saves the XML is the same, none of the node values are decoded to "<" from "$lt;"

php code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load("test.xml");
$titles = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');

foreach ($titles as $title) {

$title->nodeValue=html_entity_decode($title->nodeValue);
}
 $dom->save("success.xml")
```

Could you tell me whats wrong with it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that. What you experience is the expected (an only working) behavior.

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

1. The whole purpose of using a library is getting encoding and decoding done for you automatically.
2. If you inject a literal `<` character, you are defining an XML tag.

Assuming you have a valid reason to care about how `<` and `>` are encoded, you must use CDATA:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load("test.xml");
$titles = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');

foreach ($titles as $title) {
    $newNode = $dom->createCDATASection($title->nodeValue);
    $title->nodeValue = null;
    $title->appendChild($newNode);
}
$dom->save("success.xml");
```

... which generates:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<section id="1">
<title id="2"><![CDATA[>]]></title>
<title id="2"><![CDATA[<]]></title>
<title id="2"><![CDATA[<]]></title>
</section>
```

But this document is 100% equivalent to the one you already have (except for the missing `<?xml version="1.0"?>` heading).

**Edit #1:** entities are just a syntactic trick to *encode* special chars, they do not alter the node contents at all, and PHP decodes everything automatically for you:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load("test.xml");
$titles = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');

foreach ($titles as $title) {
    var_dump($title->nodeValue);
}
```

... prints the decoded contents as expected:

```
string(1) ">"
string(1) "<"
string(1) "<"
```

Perhaps it's easier to see with this other example:

```
echo 'O\'Brian';
```

... prints `O'Brian` and *not* `O\'Brian`. We're encoding the string, not modifying it.

I suspect that in the whole picture there's some jQuery code like this:

```
$.get('ajax/data.php', function(data) {
    $('.result').text(data);
});
```

... where there should be something like:

```
$.get('ajax/data.php', function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
});
```

**Edit #2:**

I can't even image how your authoring system works (I hope you aren't using a WYSIWYG editor to actually *type* HTML tags) but you've asked about XML and in XML there're only two things you can do you with angle brackets:

1. Data
2. Tags

In [DOMDocument](http://php.net/DOMDocument) you can create tags with [createElement()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) and you can insert the previously created tags with e.g. [appendChild()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php).

Period.

Comment: well the whole reason is encoding some style tags for html, because  this : &lt;b&gt; this would be bold text &lt;/b&gt;
renders as <b> this would be bold text </b> and not really bold text

Comment: @KukoricaJános - XML does not have the faintest idea about HTML formatting. See my edit.

Comment: well first, thanks for your answer. I know that php and html are translating those encoded chars to their normal form but in my case I need to have the normal form like : <b> or <u> or whatever because the css im using for the xml file isnt working on it if its encoded.
So all I wanted to do is replace all encoded values to their real form so the css could work.

Comment: @KukoricaJános - But you don't have to. Please read my edit again and feel free to ask for further clarifications if something is not clear.

Comment: I do get the string from a wysiwyg editor which makes <> marks into &lt; and &gt; , and its not a problem until I add a CSS file to the XML. 
In the CSS im declaring the <b> and other tags as font-weight:bold; ect. so if the xml file is opened in a browser window the text inside <b> tags are formatted as bold.
But it only works if theres <b> inside my XML file and not &lg;b$gt;

Comment: @KukoricaJános - I've added a second edit but, honestly, I doubt it'll help you at all. I'd recommend that you first try to get a static XML file what works for you (no PHP, just a text editor).

Comment: Im using the wysiwyg editor called Nicedit for creating the nodevalues of the xml file. I have another interface for selecting the nodes and creating them but that isnt the point now.
If I select a node its nodevalue is displayed inside the Nicedit box where I can edit it and even format it with Nicedit. Thats where the formating tags like <b> or <i> come from.